# I'm doing the practice project "Coin flip streaks" from Automate the Boring Stuff, and am unsure what I'm missing or doing wrong

Tags: python, coin-flipping

```
import random

numStreaks = 0

for experimentNum in range(10000):

    # Code that creates a list of 100 'heads' or 'tails' values.
    outcome = []
    
    for i in range(100):
    
        if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
            outcome.append('H')
        else:
            outcome.append('T')

    # Code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row
    Hstreak = 0

    for i in range(len(outcome)):
        for x in range(6):    
                if outcome[x] == 'H':
                    Hstreak += 1        
        if Hstreak == 6:
            numStreaks += 1
        else:
            numStreaks = 0            

print ('Chance of streak: %s%%' % (numStreaks/100))
```

I'm having trouble with the coin flip project from chapter 4. I have no idea on what I'm missing or doing wrong. I tried to run the code, but nothing comes up. I've looked up other people's takes on the project, but I still have no clue why my code doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing comes up"?

Comment: Running the code just opens up the prompt with nothing in it.

Comment: At least the final print should be executed if you are running the script correctly (even though it will most likely be 0%)

Answer (score 0):

In your

```py
        if Hstreak == 6:
            numStreaks += 1
        else:
            numStreaks = 0
```

you're setting `numStreaks` to 0 every time `HStreak` is not 6.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of errors here.
First of all, in this piece of code:

```
for x in range(6):    
    if outcome[x] == 'H':
        Hstreak += 1
```

You are only ever checking first 6 flips from each set of 100. Only if they all are 'H' will your `numStreaks` get increased.
Then, as @Emre Sahin said, you are setting your `numStreaks` to 0 every time `Hstreak` is not 6. Lastly you are not resetting your Hstreak counter at any point even if streak is broken by T. All in all, you need to rethink your logic that is behind finding the streaks.

Comment: I see. Correct me if I'm wrong (I'm a newbie), from what I understand from your comment is that my numStreaks should be = numStreaks, and add in a reset for the Hstreak whenever 'T' appears in the middle of 6 'H'?